# Cannot uninstall modules due to missing table br_schedule

Tags: database, installation

When I hit the Uninstall tab in the UI or try to uninstall a module with Drush I get the following errors:

Drush:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 
1146 Table 'DATABASENAME.br_schedule' doesn't exist
```

Drupal Log:

```
Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42S02]: 
Base table or view not found: 
1146 Table 'DATABASENAME.br_schedule' doesn't exist: 
SELECT base_table.vid AS vid, 
base_table.id AS id FROM {br_schedule} 
base_table LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0; Array ( ) in 
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->hasData() 
(line 552 of MYSITEPATH/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php).
```

I have no idea what br_schedule is so I don't know how to rebuild that table. I have Businesses Rules installed but I see no br_schedule module.

Comment: It doesn’t have to be a module necessarily, a module can create as many tables as it needs to. An easy way to get out of this is to create a bare table using a database editor/interface called br_schedule then try to uninstall the module. This will get you around the error. The rest sounds like a bug for the Business rules module.

Comment: br_schedule is the base table for the business_rules_schedule entity type. Perhaps the module was previously installed before the entity type existed in the current version. Maybe `drush updb` could solve the issue (it should run entup as well these days).

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue. My database updates are not happening. Ran updatedb:status with drush and I get:

```
file_entity                           8004        hook_update_n   Fix entity field mismatches on the file type field.
business_rules_schedule entity type               entity-update   The Schedule entity type needs to be installed.
file entity type                                  entity-update   The File type field needs to be updated.
node entity type                                  entity-update   The node.field_zipcode field needs to be updated.
```

"Fix entity field mismatches on the file type field." is failing so the "business_rules_schedule" update isn't happening.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest workaround as @kevin mentions would be to download [adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) or use existing phpmyadmin if you have and create that table with no content running the following (or similar) `SQL command`

```
CREATE TABLE br_schedule (
    ID int
);
```

then try again to see if it can uninstall

**NOTE:** use with caution its not a bulletproof technique, I have used it a few times and was able to complete broken uninstalls on messed up databases but as mradcliffe mentions it might screw things up as well.

Comment: This might cause further errors because the table is provided by a content entity type.

Comment: @mradcliffe perhaps you are right its a trial and error not to be tried on live site, I am not aware of what `br_schedule` is but the above technique has saved me a few times when I get in my hands a broken DB

Answer (score 1):

I spun up a blank D8 with Business Rules installed and exported the br_schedule table and imported it into the effected site. Now I can uninstall modules.

Answer (score 1):

Just run "drush entity-updates" to create the entities before you run drush updb.

Comment: `Drupal removed its automatic entity-updates API in 8.7. See https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742. `.